# How can I send data in MVC4 using Serialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

## MVC4 Serialization Problems

I am currently using MVC4 to handle the server side code for a project. I aim to send a list of objects to a client application using the basic MVC style.

### The Server

Which is to say, I have a "Controller" class with a function that handles basic get requests.

Here is that function:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The installer(uninstaller in this case), will need the known malicious programs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="User_ID"></param>
    /// <param name="UC"></param>
    /// <param name="Implementation_ID"></param>
    /// <returns>Sends a serialized list of extensions as an object that will be shared.</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult SendExtensions(Guid User_ID, string UC, string Implementation_ID)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----Send Serialized Malicious Extensions----");
        string ipAddress = Utility.GetIPAddress();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IP: " + ipAddress);
        string Country = GeoIPHelper.GetCountryCode(ipAddress);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Country: " + GeoIPHelper.GetCountryCode(ipAddress));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User ID: " + User_ID);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User Class: " + UC);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Implementation ID: " + Implementation_ID);
        try
        {
            using (ValidationManager manager = new ValidationManager())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Getting data from DB.");
                //Grab the users installed malicious applications. (Extensions + Programs)
                List<CheckUserExtensionsResult> userExts = manager.CheckUserExtensions(User_ID);

                //using (var stream = new StreamWriter(Request.InputStream))
                {
                    //Convert the list into an object.
                    List<BlockedExtension> sList = ConvertToSerializableList(userExts);
                    //Serializer.
                    BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
                    //Send the serialized object.
                    serializer.Serialize(Request.InputStream, sList);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

### The Client

The client application has a function to send over the user id and get back a list of malicious extensions:

```
    /// Grab a list of the installed malicious extensions.
    public static void GetMalicousExtensions(string User_ID, string UC, string Implementation_ID)
    {
        try
        {

            //         Debug
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetMalExt Running");
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://localhost:35555/Secure/SendExtensions?User_ID={0}&UC={1}&Implementation_ID={2}"
                , User_ID
                , UC
                , Implementation_ID
                ));

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Request made.");
            request.Method = "GET";

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Method set.");
            request.Timeout = 10000;//10 seconds for debug, switch to 5 for release.

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Serializer initialized.");
            BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Getting the stream.");
            var mList = (serializer.Deserialize(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()));
            //request.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetMalExt deserialized");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    ///
```

### The Serializable Object

The data being serialized is a class that will hold data about malicious extensions, right now it only stores the name of malicious extensions. None-the-less, here is the class being sent. NOTE: I am actually sending a list of the serializable objects, I don't know if that might be causing any problems.

```
    ///
///For testing, this should be moved to a shared file.
[Serializable()]
public class BlockedExtension : ISerializable
{
    string Extension_Name = "";
    public BlockedExtension(string Extension_Name)
    {
        this.Extension_Name = Extension_Name;
    }
    public BlockedExtension(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {

    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {

    }
}
```

### Finally! The Question:

So after giving you as much background as I can, the problem is when I go to send/receive the serialized data. I call the functions just fine and get responses on both ends, but I get errors on both sides once it comes time to send the serialized data.

#### The Clients Error : This is from the debug console

- Getting the stream.
- A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' - - occurred in mscorlib.dll
- Exception: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.

#### The Servers Error : This is from the debug console

- ----Send Serialized Malicious Extensions----
- IP: ::1
- Country: --
- User ID: d0ba65e1-b840-49cb-bbbb-002077050cd2
- User Class: 567
- Implementation ID: test
- Getting data from DB.
- A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I am open to any technical documents on the subject of sending serialized data through MVC4, as I haven't really found any. All of this has been put together using snippits from different types of applications. Most of the documentation I found on this subject was for use with a TCP connection, which I don't want to set up for this application.

Any help on the matter would be most appreciated.

Comment: why aren't you using wcf or web api?

Comment: Is your `GetObjectData` implementation actually empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to write into the **REQUEST** input stream with information you want to send in the **RESPONSE**.

Also, your binary view of the data is pretty specific; I think you might want to consider whether this is the appropriate server API programming model for your domain - WCF seems more applicable to the binary stream format you're pursuing.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it right up. In regards to switching to WCF, I am not in the position to make that decision, unfortunately.